# SQL Oracle - optimum query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join

I have three tables with the following schemas:

```
Persons(Person_id, Department_id, Sure_name, Name, Birthyear, Height, Manager_id)
Departments (Department_id, Department_Name, Code)
Salaries (Salary_id, Person_id, Salary)
```

I need to run a query which will display the name of the department, for which the difference between the workers' minimum and maximum heights is the greatest.

I have done it the following way:

```
select Department_Name
from Departments
where Department_id = (select Department_id
                      from Departments 
                      join Persons 
                      using (Department_id)
                      group by Department_id
                      having max(height) - min(height) = (select max(max(height) - min(height)) 
                                                          from Departments 
                                                          join Persons 
                                                          using (Department_id) 
                                                          group by Department_id));
```

And it works fine, just I'm not really sure if the solution is optimum, there are two nested queries here, I wonder if I could achieve the same in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT Department_Name
FROM   Departments D
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Department_id,
                          Max(height) - Min(height) AS diff
                   FROM   Departments
                          JOIN Persons
                            ON using (Department_id)
                   WHERE ROWNUM = 1
                   GROUP  BY Department_id
                   ORDER  BY diff DESC) B
               ON d.Department_id = b.Department_id
```

or use `Window Function`

```
SELECT Department_id,
       Department_Name
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Max(height)- Min(height) desc ) rn,
               Department_id,
               Department_Name
        FROM   Departments
               JOIN Persons
                 ON using(Department_id)
        GROUP  BY Department_id,
                  Department_Name)a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: you can even group by department name additionally to omit outer join

Comment: Is inner join equivalent to join? Plus, I don't think 'limit' will work on Oracle.

Comment: @user4359659 - Join is equal to Inner Join. added another answer

Comment: I'm not quite certain one can put aggregates in the `OVER( )` clause of a window function. And you won't want to `PARTITION BY department_id`.

Comment: @DavidFaber - yeah `partition by` is not needed here. As far i know you can use aggregate in `order by`

Comment: The 2nd  has syntax error (join Persons ON using), and it doesn't produce the same result. In the 1st, I can't use a WHERE clause after GROUP BY.

Comment: @NoDisplayName, you are correct, aggregates do work in window functions! However, I would use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` as there could be a tie.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, a bit complicated but using the analytic function `RANK()` probably simplifies things a bit over using nothing but aggregates:

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, d.code, p1.height_diff
  FROM departments d INNER JOIN (
    SELECT department_id, height_diff, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY height_diff DESC ) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT department_id, MAX(height) - MIN(height) AS height_diff
          FROM Persons
         GROUP BY department_id
      )
  ) p1
    ON d.department_id = p1.department_id
 WHERE p1.rn = 1;
```

[Please see SQL Fiddle demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beb1c/2) **N.B. I had previously ordered incorrectly, now corrected to `DESC`.**

Comment: Editing ... missing a closing parenthesis.